# Does [bytes] automatically release the memory without having to use free?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, free

I have a C API I call into as follows:

```
- (NSData*)getFileContents {
     NSData *fileContents;

     //do something 

     return fileContents;
}

-(void*) manipulateFile {
    UInt8 *data = (UInt8*) [[self getFileContents] bytes];
    UInt32 dataLength = (UInt32)[[self getFileContents] length]; 

     //call some C API with the data and dataLength value
```

}

Now my question as I don't have to explicitly call `free(data)` I am wondering what is happening under the hood of `bytes` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself this - did you explicitly call `malloc` and friends? Does the documentation for `NSData bytes` state that ownership of the pointer is passed to the caller?

Since the answer is no to both questions, then no, you do not (and must not) call `free`.

Your bigger concern is the valid lifetime of the pointer. Make no attempt to use it beyond the lifetime of the `NSData` object.

Comment: I figured as much when my program crashed (Haha). I am just wondering why that is the case and what is happening under the hood. Sorry should've been clear

Comment: The `bytes` property is passing you a pointer that is owned by the `NSData` instance. The `NSData` instance owns that memory. It is responsible for it. It is not giving you a copy. Therefore, since you don't own the pointer, you must not free it.